# Areaspline: edge to edge lines and hide first y label

Tags: highcharts

I received a mockup of a graph using an areaspline (ignoring the column chart):

[image: graph]

I have two questions that I can't seem to find any configuration that would satisfy the requirements.

1. Is there a way to extend the lines to the edge of the graph based on their trending slope, or possibly just a little above or below the end point? On a graph like this, it wouldn't look bad to omit those edge lines, but on a graph in the same area with only 3 data points, the whitespace is much more noticeable.
2. I have the y-axis labels stepping every other, but I can't seem to find a way to hide the first label ($0) in this case. Aside from just hiding the text element itself, is there a configuration to do this?

**Edit**: Here's an example of my configuration:

```
var themeColors = {
    primaryColor: '#067bc2',    //dark blue
    secondaryColor: '#6a61a7',  //dark purple
    tertiaryColor: '#5ccadc',   //turquoise
    darkGray: '#37383e',        //dark gray
    mediumGray: '#919aa2',      //medium gray
    mediumLightGray: '#c9d3dc', //medium blue gray
    lightGray: '#eaf1f8',       //light blue gray (hover color)
    primaryRed: '#e54443',
    secondaryRed: '#e54443',
    primaryGreen: '#2bbb2d',
    secondaryGreen: '#2bbb2d',
    primaryOrange: '#ffa883',   //peach
    primaryBackground: '#fafcfe',//light blue
    secondaryBackground: '#ffffff',
    primaryText: '#37383e',     //dark gray
    secondaryText: '#919aa2',   //medium gray
    selectedColor: '#f5fafd'    //light blue, slightly darker than background
};

var colors = [
  themeColors.secondaryColor,
  themeColors.tertiaryColor,
  themeColors.primaryOrange
];

(function renderChart(series) {
  var options = {
    chart: {
      height: 400,
      spacing: [0,0,0,0],
      type: 'areaspline',
    },
    colors: colors,
    credits: { enabled: false },
    legend: {
      align: 'left',
      itemStyle: {
        color: themeColors.secondaryText,
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
      },
      margin: 30,
      symbolHeight: 14,
      symbolRadius: 0,
      symbolWidth: 14,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      areaspline: {
        marker: {
          fillColor: themeColors.secondaryBackground,
          lineColor: null,
          lineWidth: 2,
          radius: 3,
          symbol: 'circle',
        }
      }
    },
    title: { text: null },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
      crosshair: {
        color: Highcharts.color(themeColors.lightGray).setOpacity(.5).get('rgba'),
        width: 12
      },
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: themeColors.secondaryText,
          fontSize: '12px'
        }
      },
      lineColor: themeColors.lightGray,
      tickColor: themeColors.lightGray,
      tickWidth: 0,
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineColor: themeColors.lightGray,
      labels: {
        align: 'left',
        step: 2,
        style: {
          color: themeColors.secondaryText,
          fontSize: '12px'
        },
        x: 0,
        y: 12,
      },
      lineColor: themeColors.lightGray,
      tickColor: themeColors.lightGray,
      title: { text: null },
    },
  };

  series.forEach((s,i)=>{
    s.fillColor = {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        y1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, Highcharts.color(colors[i]).setOpacity(0.1).get('rgba')],
        [1, Highcharts.color(colors[i]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
      ]
    };
  });

  options.series = series;

    Highcharts.chart('container',options);
})([
    { name: 'a', data:[1,4,2] },
  { name: 'b', data:[3,1,2] }
]);
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mtowj6ng/

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you share a live example with all you have try so far ?

Comment: @Core972 Updated question - jsfiddle is at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can set min and max of the axis.

   ```
   xAxis: {
     categories: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
     min: 0.5,
     max: 1.5,
   ```

If you have 3 categories, the axis range will be 0 - 2, so you can increase the min and decrease the max in the amount of 0.5 (the middle of the category).

You can also do it dynamically by updating the xAxis with [xAxis.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update) on chart load.

```
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function () {
          const min = Math.min.apply(null, this.series[0].xData)
          const max = Math.max.apply(null, this.series[0].xData)

          this.xAxis[0].update({
            min: min + 0.5,
            max: max - 0.5
          })
        }
      }
    },
```

You can also do it before you render the chart.

2. Set [yAxis.showFirstLabel](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.showFirstLabel) to false.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/bbd3pu9j/

Comment: Thanks - For #1, I've looked into this option, but I'm wondering if it is possible to have something matching the mockup more closely - namely having the points and labels still spaced, but having the extra lines extend so the points are still visible.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to define two additional points on the left and the right side - Highcharts needs to know where to place the point to draw the line. Those points must be calculated based on the data. With two additional points, extend categories to have two empty categories ['', 'first', ..., 'last', ''] and adjust min and max. https://jsfiddle.net/bbd3pu9j/1/